# Showing list of elements in recyclerView failed

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to make a news app, data obtained from RSS feed. I get xml response from the feed. And I am using XmlPullParser to parse the xml. The parsing is a success. I can see the values in my log.

But somehow I am not able to fill them in my recyclerView. It's all just blank. My java class is:

```
public class RssNewsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = RssNewsActivity.class.toString();

RssFeedAdapter adapter;
RecyclerView recyclerView_rssFeed;
SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

private List<RssModel> listResponseModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rss_news);

    initialize();

    recyclerView_rssFeed.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView_rssFeed.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    adapter = new RssFeedAdapter(RssNewsActivity.this, listResponseModel);
    recyclerView_rssFeed.setAdapter(adapter);

    fetchNewsFeed();

    //if user swipes the recycler then refresh content page
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            fetchNewsFeed();
        }
    });
}

private void initialize() {
    swipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh_rssFeed);
    recyclerView_rssFeed = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_rssFeed);

    listResponseModel = new ArrayList<>();
}

private void fetchNewsFeed() {
    String url = "here is my news feed url";
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            listResponseModel.clear();
            try {
                listResponseModel = parseNewsFeed(response);
            } catch (XmlPullParserException | IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    queue.add(request);

}

private List<RssModel> parseNewsFeed(String response) throws XmlPullParserException,
        IOException {

    XmlPullParserFactory parserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    parserFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    XmlPullParser xmlPullParser = parserFactory.newPullParser();
    xmlPullParser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
    xmlPullParser.setInput(new StringReader(response));

    return processParsing(xmlPullParser);
}

private List<RssModel> processParsing(XmlPullParser xmlPullParser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    List<RssModel> listRssFeed = new ArrayList<>();
    int eventType = xmlPullParser.getEventType();
    RssModel rssModel = null;

    xmlPullParser.nextTag();
    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        String eltName;
        switch (eventType) {
            case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                eltName = xmlPullParser.getName();
                if ("item".equals(eltName)) {
                    rssModel = new RssModel();
                } else if (rssModel != null) {
                    if ("title".equals(eltName)) {
                        String title = xmlPullParser.nextText();
                        rssModel.setTitle(title);
                        Log.d(TAG, "title: " + title);
                    } else if ("link".equals(eltName)) {
                        String link = xmlPullParser.nextText();
                        rssModel.setLink(link);
                        Log.d(TAG, "link: " + link);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                eltName = xmlPullParser.getName();
                if ("item".equals(eltName) && rssModel != null) {
                    listRssFeed.add(rssModel);
                }
                break;
        }
        eventType = xmlPullParser.next();
    }
    return listRssFeed;
}
}
```

my xml design is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="rssnewsfeed.RssNewsActivity">

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefresh_rssFeed"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView_rssFeed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my adapter class

```
public class RssFeedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RssFeedAdapter.RssViewHolder> {
private Context mContext;
private List<RssModel> mRssFeeds;

public RssFeedAdapter(Context mContext, List<RssModel> mRssFeeds) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mRssFeeds = mRssFeeds;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RssViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.rss_feed_layout, viewGroup, false);
    return new RssViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RssViewHolder rssViewHolder, int i) {
    RssModel post = mRssFeeds.get(i);

    rssViewHolder.textView_title.setText(post.getTitle());
    rssViewHolder.textView_link.setText(post.getLink());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mRssFeeds.size();
}

public class RssViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView textView_title, textView_link;

    public RssViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_title);
        textView_link = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_link);
    }

}
}
```

And finally this is my model class:

```
public class RssModel {
private String title;
private String link;

public RssModel() {
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getLink() {
    return link;
}

public void setLink(String link) {
    this.link = link;
}
}
```

I tried many ways but no success. I don't know what I am missing. I will be grateful for any guidance. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving " = " will create a new instance of `ArrayList` apart from which is already binded to `RecyclerView` adapter.

So, you need to change this,

```
listResponseModel = parseNewsFeed(response);
```

to

```
listResponseModel.addAll(parseNewsFeed(response));
```

Comment: @Ujjwal Jung Thapa giving '=' will create a new instance of array list apart from which is already binded to recycler view adapter

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the Rss list which you're passing to recycler view adapter is null as you mentioned earlier you're successfully getting the values in log so another guaranteed workaround is to set the values into an separate arraylist.

So inside your class simply create arraylist:

```
private ArrayList<String> title;

private ArrayList<String> post;
```

This will be your initialize method:

```
private void initialize() 
{
       swipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh_rssFeed);
       recyclerView_rssFeed = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_rssFeed);

       title = new ArrayList<>();

       post = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Now simply pass your values to arraylist:

```
title.add(title)

post.add(post)
```

Now pass those arraylist to adapter:

```
adapter = new RssFeedAdapter(RssNewsActivity.this, title,post);
    recyclerView_rssFeed.setAdapter(adapter);
```

After this initialize arraylist in adapter and fetch your values!

One more Important thing inside your `oncreate()` place your `fetchNewsFeed();` method before initializing the adapter

```
 initialize();
fetchNewsFeed();
  recyclerView_rssFeed.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView_rssFeed.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    adapter = new RssFeedAdapter(RssNewsActivity.this, listResponseModel);
    recyclerView_rssFeed.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: after this if still you're facing problem then i would suggest you to check your rss_feed_layout.xml